Movie with possible alien invasion and purple challenger
So I vaguely remember watching a movie a few years back. I remember bits and pieces that I'm hoping will lead me to the results. 
The movie has a scene where there are a bunch of people on a rooftop waiting for? Possibly aliens or something to happen, they are all holding signs. 
A little later one of the characters goes to a friends house who is having as much sex with as many different women as he can before? Possibly the world ending, and I do remember that when the character walks in he passes a woman and questions his friend if that was there teacher from school, I believe he than borrows his friends muscle car? Possibly a purple challenger and than I left and didn't catch the rest, anybody out there please help, it's been bugging me for too long

I think you might be thinking Signs (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0286106/) but not sure. I know the scene you are mentioning vividly but placing it is more difficult.

Sounds like it may be the interesting Canadian movie LAST NIGHT where it's the end of the world, and everyone knows it, but no explanation is given. One man is trying to bed as many of his desires as possible, and there's even a hook-up between a teacher and ex-student. (It's the last night before the world ends...) 
Here is the trailer, and a poor copy of the movie on YouTube.

Well, the "his friend has end-of-the-world sex with their ex-teacher then lends him his muscle car" bit definitely fits, except it's a lime-green Super Bee. Maybe Joe's TV was on the fritz. ;) BTW, there's a similar friend in Seeking a Friend for the End of the World, but the car thing doesn't fit.
